# Pass DB credential with htaccess

Tags: php, database, apache, security

I'm trying to protect an inc file who contains some data base informations , i'm using htacess to protect that file.

What i want is the following : allow only the php script to get those informations to log to the DB .

My Webroot looks like this:[imgWebRoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ibmI.png)

My .htacess code looks like this  :

```
<files sql.cnf>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
allow from indexa.php
</files>
```

My php file :

```
   parse_ini_file("C:\Apache24\htdocs\sql.cnf");
    echo $_SERVER[‘DB_LOGIN’]; // login
```

My sql.cnf File

```
SetEnv DB_LOGIN “login”
SetEnv DB_PASSWD “password”
SetEnv DB_DB “my_database”
SetEnv DB_HOST “127.0.0.1”
```

My probleme is that i can't log to the php file , and i don't understand why ?

[ImgError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fz7V.png)

[zf.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ibmI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache, you can add the variables to the end of your httpd.conf file as shown below, and then access them by referencing the $_SERVER global:

```
SetEnv VAR_NAME strongpassword123
```

I do not believe the values need to be quoted. After restarting the Apache service, you will be able to reference your value using `$_SERVER['VAR_NAME']`. No need to `parse_ini_file` a separate file in the app logic.

Additionally, you should not rely on htaccess to protect credentials. If you need to store credentials in a file on the app server instead of as environment variables, they should be stored ABOVE the web root.

For example, the code below would find a file stored one level above the webroot in a directory named config.

```
require("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/../config/config.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's very helpfull, do you have an idea how to make cofig.php accessable only by  index.php (file in the root) ?

Comment: @Alae - are you trying to prevent other PHP scripts from accessing the config file?

Comment: yes and espeacialy for maintain the security of the db credentials ( no one could have access to theese informations = no one can open/read the config file )

Comment: right - so I would strongly suggest storing them as environment variables using the httpd.conf file. The reality is that any PHP script executing on your app server has to be trusted to some extent. I am not aware of a way to restrict access to a file to a single PHP script. If a malicious user has access to the source code, they could simply overwrite your index file to dump the credentials.